# Double clicking in tables: Don't select the other cells

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, user-interface

When I double click on a cell, it selects the contents of that cell (good) but also the cell to the right of it.

[image: Example]

My TDs are floating:

```
#addresstable td{
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
}
```

I've tried applying the no select CSS rule to the label, however the cell is still selected with the text copied :/

How do I make it so that when I double click on Address, it only selects the address and not the label?

Entire code (from Chrome Inspect element):

```
<table id="addresstable" class="table table-bordered">
<tbody><tr class="hidden-phone gradient"><td><strong>Address</strong></td><td>Label</td><td>Actions</td></tr>
<tr><td class="small">mncFbqoSgv8nEM1nREGTtS6qNwLRYkjV8K</td><td><span class="addresslabel noselect" data-address="mncFbqoSgv8nEM1nREGTtS6qNwLRYkjV8K">Default</span></td><td><a href="javascript:;" class="editaddresslabel btn" data-address="mncFbqoSgv8nEM1nREGTtS6qNwLRYkjV8K"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Label</a> <a href="javascript:;" class="qrcode btn" data-address="mncFbqoSgv8nEM1nREGTtS6qNwLRYkjV8K" data-original-title=""><i class="icon-qrcode"></i></a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: can we see the code for the entire html table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to make sure your HTML is well-formed. I built the markup for your example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/fXfsC/1

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Address
            </td>
            <td>
                Label
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                lkjsdflkjsdflkjsdflkjsdfl                
            </td>
            <td>
                Default
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I double click on the address td, it only selects the td. If you still have trouble after verifying your markup, please post your code and I'll take a look.

Comment: I hate `border-collapse: separate`. It makes tables look so weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Not sure why it happened - as clearly @mchail jsfiddle shows a simple table should work just fine..

Maybe it had something to do with the jade/pug I was using, or angular..

Either way - I simply solved it by wrapping the cell's content with div.
So my pug file looked like so:

```
table
  tr
    td
      div This is the content
    td something else
```

And when I double clicked on "This is the content" is selected just that.